# Why is the max number of users reached when there is only really one?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am trying to make a website that is a bit heavy on queries `(~2)` every few seconds per user. So, after being on the website for a while, I get the message

> "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1226): User has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 1500) in connect.php on line 2". This file is included in every php file where needed.

Here is the `connect.php` :

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('...', '...', '...');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error(!connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, '2014998_lootcash');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error(!connection));
}
?>
```

(I deleted the private info) So, there is only me on the website. Why does it keep giving me the message. I thought it would be because I didn't close the connection, but at the end of every script, I put `"mysqli_close($connection)"`, and it still happens.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you share the connection , do you call it in a loop? ... to little information here

Comment: What do you mean share? And I said there are scripts that call queries every few seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it would be because I didn't close the connection

Even if it's a good pratice to close explicity the connection, PHP close implicitly any resource  at the end of the script. Anyhow, seems to me that you've misunderstood the error message. The user that you used to connecting to the database has a limited number of connections allowed per hour. That's mean that every time you request a page that require `connect.php`, you've consumed one of those connections.

To increase this limits you can run this query:

```
ALTER USER 'youruser'@'localhost' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 3000;
```

You can remove the limit by setting it to zero.

Comment: Hmm.. So, Is there a way to increase this number?

Comment: Do you have access to the database?

Comment: Yes I do have access.

Comment: Hello? You said MAX_QUERIES, when I am looking for max_connections...This is wrong :(

Comment: you're right, I've make a mistake to report the correct option - thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html) you can use something like this to unlimited connections:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'francis'@'localhost' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0;
```